# Error Loading "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:3000/app/main.js

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am struggling diagnosing this error. It says it can't load from my main.js but my main.js is loading just fine... I think I am missing an app.set statement. or a reference of some sort, I just dont know what. here is a little bit of my code, I am trying to create a MEAN stack with Angular2 as my front end.

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**server.ts**

```
en///<reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts"/>

import express = require('express');
import path = require('path');

let port: number = process.env.port || 3000;
let app = express();


app.set('views', './src/client/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use("/node_modules", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules')));
app.use("/app", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/client/app')));

app.use("/*.html", function (req, res) {
    res.render(req.params[0] + ".html");
});

app.get('/', function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
           res.render('index.html')
})

let server = app.listen(port, function () {
let host = server.address().address;
let port = server.address().port;

console.log("Express app is listening on port: " + port);
});
```

am I not referencing the packages or something?? Thanks ahead of time for any help.

**edit:** here is the error....

```
Error loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:3000/app/main.js"
```

**tscongif**

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false
 }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also it might be worth knowing that I am following this tutorial  [here](https://blog.sashank.xyz/tutorial-hello-world-mean-stack-app-with-angular-2-mongoose-basic-part-1-2041ffa8b0d3#.mndgsamh2)  but I am using angular 2 rc.5

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? Can you please show your tsconfig and the module loader file (are you using systemjs perhaps)?

Comment: Yes I am using typescript, updated the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue, The path to my systemjs.config.js was wrong.

Comment: could you elaborate on this? Having the same issue

Comment: Error loading `http://localhost:3000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:3000/main.js`, I tried changing path from       `'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js'` to       `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',` but doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: src/main.ts, I removed the changes

Comment: `    <script>
      $.material.init();
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>`

Comment: Omg, so sorry, accidentally got out of the chat, and now can't seem to be able to find it!!! thanks so much!!! you saved me days of wondering around!! :D